# fast way to network transfer a lot of small files with PHP

Tags: php

I have 2 Linux servers on the same LAN.
Using PHP i need to copy 100000 small (10KB) files from Server A to Server B.

Now i'm using ssh2_scp_send and its very slow(10K files in 20 minutes).

How to make it faster?

Comment: its a possible but more complicated solution.

Comment: FTP is usually the fastest solution.

Comment: If you copy using the cmd line is it any faster? Is the slow part the php function or just the overhead of copying lots of small files?

Comment: @bumperbox i think its overhead. just creating all those files will takes seconds

Comment: It's not so hard to archive them you can go with command line if possible or php have lots of classes for that even extensions like Phar. I believe you can even find example in SO..

Comment: updated by answer with a PHP solution

Answer (score 4):

Using gzipped TAR through an SSH tunnel is blazing fast. Magnitudes faster than pure `scp`, particularly with regard to many small files. Here is an example for the *linux command line*:

> user@local# cd /source/ ; tar czf - * | ssh user@remote "cd /target/ ; tar xzf -"

---

*Update:* As requested, here you go with a pure PHP solution - had some fun fiddling out this tricky bit.

Note: You need [PHPs libssh extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) for this to work. Also, STDIN seems to be only available when using the stream wrappers for SSH.

This has almost no overhead, because it is operating on streams directly and your CPU is most likely always faster than the network link you are using for the transfer.

To trade of network vs. CPU speed, you can remove the option `-z` from the command line. (less CPU usage, but more data on the wire)

Code example:

```
<?php
$local_cmd = "cd /tmp/source && tar -czf - *";
$remote_cmd = "tar -C /tmp/target -xzf -";

$ssh = new SSH_Connection('localhost');
$auth = $ssh->auth_password('gast', 'gast');
$bytes = $ssh->command_pipe($local_cmd, $remote_cmd);
echo "finished: $bytes bytes of data transfered\n";

class SSH_Connection {
    private $link;
    private $auth;

    function __construct ($host, $port=22) {
        $this->link = @ssh2_connect('localhost', 22);
    }  

    function auth_password ($username, $password) {
        if (!is_resource($this->link))
            return false;
        $this->auth = @ssh2_auth_password($this->link, $username, $password); 
        return $this->auth;
    }   

    function command_pipe ($localcmd, $remotecmd) {
        if (!is_resource($this->link) || !$this->auth)
            return false;
        // open remote command stream (STDIN)
        $remote_stream = fopen("ssh2.exec://{$this->link}/$remotecmd", 'rw');
        if (!is_resource($remote_stream))
            return false;
        // open local command stream (STDOUT)
        $local_stream = popen($localcmd, 'r');
        if (!is_resource($local_stream))
            return false;
        // connect both, pipe data from local to remote
        $bytes = 0;
        while (!feof($local_stream)) 
            $bytes += fwrite($remote_stream,fread($local_stream,8192));
        // close streams
        fclose($local_stream);
        fclose($remote_stream);
        return $bytes; 
    }   

    function is_connected () { return is_resource($this->link); }
    function is_authenticated () { return $this->auth; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you execute external process via PHP? If you can, rsync is the faster way to do the copy

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be Zip:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive();

if ($zip->open('TempFileToTransfer.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}

$zip->addFile('File 1');
$zip->addFile('File 2');
$zip->addFile('File 3');
$zip->close();
?>
```

Transfer that one file and uncompress at the other end, and use zip_entry_open and zip_entry_read at the other.

I'd also suggest in chunks of say 1000 files at a time?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the overhead of sending lots of small files is the slowdown here.

You could archive it on your local server,
    shell_exec()

send it to the remote server,
    ssh2_scp_send()

then expand it at the other end.
    ssh2_exec()

My feeling is that the overhead of archving/expanding will be less, but I haven't tested this.